# CSS: Change element's bacgkground on hover: only changes a child's background instead of a parent's (fiddle, pictures)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

**html**:

```
<div class="item">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.item {
    border: 2px dashed green;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.item :hover  {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

I'm trying to change all of the item's color to the yellow on hover. However, only the text's background color changes:

[image]

while I want this:

[image]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/87qd0au9/

Comment: remove the space between `item` and `:hover`

Comment: `.item :hover` means that any of the item's children will be affected, since there is a space.`.item:hover` means that the parent is affected.

Comment: @fcalderan mind.blown! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the space between item and hover

```
.item:hover  {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the space between `item` and `:hover`.

**Explanation:** In CSS, the space character is a "child selector", meaning that with the space you are not targeting the `item` div, but its children.